# What SQL query or view will show "dynamic columns"

Tags: sql, database, metadata, dataview

I have a table of data, and I allow people to add meta data to that table.

I give them an interface that allows them to treat it as though they're adding extra columns to the table their data is stored in, but I'm actually storing the data in another table.

```
Data Table
   DataID
   Data

Meta Table
   DataID
   MetaName
   MetaData
```

So if they wanted a table that stored the data, the date, and a name, then I'd have the data in the data table, and the word "Date" in metaname, and the date in MetaData, and another row in the meta table with "Name" in metaname and the name in metadata.

I now need a query that takes the information from these tables and presents it as though coming from a single table with the two additional columns "Data" and "Name" so to the customer it would look like there's a single table with their custom columns:

```
MyTable
   Data
   Date
   Name
```

Or, in other words, how do I go from here:

```
Data Table
   DataID        Data
   1             Testing!
   2             Hello, World!

Meta Table
   DataID        MetaName         MetaData
   1             Date             20081020
   1             Name             adavis
   2             Date             20081019
   2             Name             mdavis
```

To here:

```
MyTable
   Data          Date             Name
   Testing!      20081020         adavis
   Hello, World! 20081019         mdavis
```

Years ago when I did this in MySQL using PHP, I did two queries, the first to get the extra meta data, the second to join them all together.  I'm hoping that modern databases have alternate methods of dealing with this.

Related to option 3 of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218848/design-decision-dynamically-adding-data-question#218872).

-Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pivot each of your name-value pair rows in the MyTable...  Try this sql:

```
DECLARE @Data   TABLE (
    DataID      INT IDENTITY(1,1)   PRIMARY KEY,
    Data        VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @Meta   TABLE (
    DataID      INT ,
    MetaName    VARCHAR(MAX),
    MetaData    VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT 'Data'

INSERT INTO @Meta
SELECT 1, 'Date', CAST(GetDate() as VARCHAR(20))
UNION
SELECT 1, 'Name', 'Joe Test'

SELECT * FROM @Data

SELECT * FROM @Meta

SELECT 
    D.DataID,
    D.Data,
    MAX(CASE MetaName WHEN 'Date' THEN MetaData ELSE NULL END) as Date,
    MAX(CASE MetaName WHEN 'Name' THEN MetaData ELSE NULL END) as Name
FROM
    @Meta M
JOIN    @Data D     ON M.DataID = D.DataID  
GROUP BY
    D.DataID,
    D.Data
```

Comment: More on CASE the crowbar of SQL. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102704-1.shtml

Comment: What is the best way to query the result? Example: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name = 'Joe Test'`  Would I need to save the first results and query that table? Or is there a way to impliment a `WHERE` filter in the first pass?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DataTable.Data AS Data, MetaTable.MetaData AS Date, MetaTable.MetaName AS Name
FROM DataTable, MetaTable
WHERE DataTable.DataID = MetaTable.DataID
```

You'll probably want to add an additional clause (AND Data = 'some value') to return the rows the user is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can do this on the server-side only with a dynamic `SQL` stored procedure.

Effectively the code you want to generate dynamically is:

```
SELECT [Data Table].*
    ,[MyTable Date].MetaData
    ,[MyTable Name].MetaData
FROM [Data Table]
LEFT JOIN [MyTable] AS [MyTable Date]
    ON [MyTable Date].DataID = [Data Table].DataID
    AND [MyTable Date].MetaName = 'Date'
LEFT JOIN [MyTable] AS [MyTable Name]
    ON [MyTable Name].DataID = [Data Table].DataID
    AND [MyTable Name].MetaName = 'Name'
```

And here's code to do it:

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @select_list AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @join_list AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @CRLF AS varchar(2)
DECLARE @Tab AS varchar(1)

SET @CRLF = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SET @Tab = CHAR(9)

SELECT @select_list = COALESCE(@select_list, '')
                        + @Tab + ',[MyTable_' + PIVOT_CODE + '].[MetaData]' + @CRLF
        ,@join_list = COALESCE(@join_list, '')
                        + 'LEFT JOIN [MyTable] AS [MyTable_' + PIVOT_CODE + ']' + @CRLF
                            + @Tab + 'ON [MyTable_' + PIVOT_CODE + '].DataID = [DataTable].DataID'  + @CRLF
                            + @Tab + 'AND [MyTable_' + PIVOT_CODE + '].MetaName = ''' + PIVOT_CODE + '''' + @CRLF
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MetaName AS PIVOT_CODE
    FROM [MyTable]
) AS PIVOT_CODES

SET @sql = 'SELECT [DataTable].*' + @CRLF
            + @select_list
            + 'FROM [DataTable]' + @CRLF
            + @join_list
PRINT @sql
--EXEC (@sql)
```

You could use a similar dynamic technique using the `CASE` statement example to perform the pivot.

Comment: So this is the two query option, where I first find out what 'dynamic' columns I need to pull in from the meta table, and then construct a query from those results?

Comment: Yes, however, you can do this dynamically in a single stored proc.  If your MetaNames are fixed, you can use the query above as is, but otherwise, it's going to be dynamic.  I'll post some code shortly which gens it quickly.

Comment: Thanks, that would be helpful.  Would you also mention which SQL server you know this to work on?

Comment: This will work on SQL Server, using the SELECT trick to make the dynamic strings without a cursor.  On other platforms there's a CONCAT or you might have to use a cursor.  The query it generates should be ANSI enough (you'll have to watch for bad characters in table names or in MetaName).